# Too many filter matching in pig

Tags: filter, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a list of filter keywords (about 1000 in numbers) and I need to filter a field of a relation in pig using this list.

Initially, I have declared these keywords like:
%declare p1 '.*keyword1.*';
....
...

%declare p1000 '.*keyword1000.*';

I am then doing filtering like:

Filtered= FITLER SRC BY (not $0 matches '$p1') and (not $0 matches '$p2') and ...... (not $0 matches '$p1000');

DUMP Filtered;

Assume that my source relation is in SRC and I need to apply filtering on first field i.e. $0.

If I am reducing the number of filters to 100-200, it's working fine. But as number of filters increases to 1000. It doesn't work.

Can somebody suggest a work around to get the results right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple filter UDF where you'd perform all the checks something like:

```
 package myudfs;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import org.apache.pig.FilterFunc;
 import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

 public class MYFILTER extends FilterFunc
 {
    static List<String> filterList;
    static MYFILTER(){
        //load all filters
    }
    public Boolean exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
            String str = (String)input.get(0);
           return !filterList.contains(str);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you give me slight overview to how I shall link my user defined functions in the driver pig script.

Comment: look at the REGISTER and DEFINE functions in the docs http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/basic.html#register

Answer (score 0):

One shallow approach is to divide the filtration into stages. Filter keywords 1 to 100 in stage one and then filter another 100  and so on for a total of (count(keywords)/100) stages. However, given more details of your data, there is probably a better solution to this.

As for the above shallow solution, you can wrap the pig script in a shell script that does the parcelling out of input and starts the run on the current keyword subset being filtered.