# Apache Pig: Easier way to filter by a bunch of values from the same field

Tags: hadoop, filter, apache-pig

Say I want select a subset of data by their values of from the same field. Right now I have to do something like this

```
TestLocationsResults = FILTER SalesData by (StoreId =='17'
or StoreId =='85'
or StoreId =='12'
or StoreId =='45'
or StoreId =='26'
or StoreId =='75'
or StoreId =='13'
)
```

in SQL, we can simply do this :

```
SELECT * FROM SalesData where StoreID IN (17, 12, 85, 45, 26, 75, 13)
```

Is there a similiar shortcut in Pig that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no IN keyword in Pig to do this sort of set membership detection.

One suggestion if to write a UDF (as seen in [this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349618/too-many-filter-matching-in-pig)).

Another could be to create a relationship with values for each `StoreId` you want to filter by and then perform an inner join on the two relationships.

Comment: This is a great idea. we def need to tag the StoreId's better. much thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Pig 0.12 added an `IN` operator](http://hortonworks.com/blog/announcing-apache-pig-0-12/).

So you can do

```
FILTER SalesData BY StoreID IN (17, 12, 85, 45, 26, 75, 13);
```

Answer (score 1):

One work around could be to use a built in function "INDEXOF"
Ex:

```
TestLocationsResults = FILTER SalesData by INDEXOF(',17,12,85,45,26,75,13,', CONCAT(CONCAT(',', StoreId), ',')) > -1;
```

Amended to take into account the comment, introduce the ',' symbols around StoreId to have the exact match and not a partial

Comment: This will not give correct results.  What if `StoreID` is `5`?  It will match the `5` in `85`.  In fact, in this particular example, any single-digit `StoreID` will match except for 9, even though none of them are desired.  This will only work if all `StoreID`s can be assumed to be of the same length, or at least that no `StoreID` is a substring of any other.

Comment: thanks for spotting this, amended the answer to take that into account

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this, when the data type is `chararray`, is to use a regular expression:

```
TestLocationsResults = FILTER SalesData by StoreID MATCHES '(17|12|85|45|26|75|13)';
```

When the data type is an `int`, you could try casting to a `chararray`.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're currently doing it is the best way to do it in Pig. All of the alternatives to what you're doing now are either hacky, slow, or both. Hopefully, Pig adds an "in" query in a future version, but for now you're doing it the best way available.